# Mariadb: ER_PARSE_ERROR, how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I made sql query for mariadb 10.1

but, I upgrade mariadb 10.1 to 10.3, but it occurs ER_PARSE_ERROR and SQL syntax error.

This error is:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage:
 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
  corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
  use near \')\' at line 1',
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'select * from user where identifier in ()' }
```

What's wrong is it?

I keep looking, but I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: Was this error in your code?  Or in the upgrade processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to like the empty list. Try to change the query.

```
select * from user where identifier in (null)
```

Null won't match any value (even another null) so this is effectively, what you seem to want.